# Kann man diesen Genitiv am Ende des Satzes benutzen?

Tags: grammatical-case, genitive

> Da niemand seine Poesie versteht, fängt er an zu glauben, dass seine Gedanken und Gefühle wichtiger und realer seien als die *Anderer*.

Achte auf das »*Anderer*« am Ende des Satzes. Ist diese Form korrekt oder muss man auf einen Dativ ausweichen wie »*von Anderen*« oder sogar den Satz neu strukturieren?

Comment: Ja, diese Form ist korrekt. Kannst du genauer konkretisieren, warum das für dich fraglich ist? Dann kann man noch genauer antworten.

Comment: Kam mir komisch vor. Wahrscheinlich weil ich wenig lese oder weil ein Freund einen Satz in diesem Format falsch geschrieben hat und ich mich dadurch unsicher gefühlt habe.

Comment: Völlig korrekt, aber heute unüblich. Der Genitiv befindet sich generell auf dem Rückzug. (Wohin das voraussichtlich führt, kann man in deutschen Dialekten und im Niederländischen sehen.) Manche Verwendungen sind noch absolut üblich (sogar im Niederländischen!), andere praktisch gar nicht mehr. Diese Verwendung ist nahe dem unüblichen Ende des Spektrums. Für jüngere Menschen, die nicht viel alte Literatur gelesen haben, kann so etwas schwer zu verstehen sein. Deshalb ist es heute guter Stil, das zu vermeiden. Und das befördert den Prozess natürlich noch weiter.

Comment: Ich spreche Schweizer Dialekt. Ich muss eingestehen, dass ich einige Probleme habe mit Deklinationen wie z.B. der Unterschied zwischen "diesem" und "diesen".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In deinem Beispielsatz wurde die Wiederholung von *Gedanken und Gefühle* ausgelassen; vollständiger hieße es:

> […] dass seine Gedanken und Gefühle wichtiger und realer seien als die *Gedanken und Gefühle* Anderer.

Hierbei merkt man auch sofort, dass sich *Anderer* sowohl auf *Gedanken* als auch *Gefühle* bezieht, und man es theoretisch ebenfalls doppeln könnte:

> […] dass seine Gedanken und Gefühle wichtiger und realer seien als die Gedanken *Anderer* und die Gefühle Anderer.

Schließlich könnte man noch einwenden, dass es sich bei *Anderer* um ein substantiviertes Adjektiv handelt, das mit einem Substantiv erneut ergänzt werden könnte, um zum Beispiel folgendes zu geben:

> […] dass seine Gedanken und Gefühle wichtiger und realer seien als die anderer *Leute.*

Im Deutschen ist der nachgestellte Genitiv, um ein Besitzverhältnis auszudrücken, zulässig; oft wird der Genitiv aber auch vorangestellt *(anderer Leute Gedanken).* Beide Varianten gestattet die deutsche Grammatik grundsätzlich; andere Sprachen (zum Beispiel Französisch mit ausschließlich nachgestelltem Genitiv oder Finnisch mit ausschließlich vorangestelltem Genitiv) können andere Regeln haben. Ob er voran- oder nachgestellt ist, hat hier keine Auswirkung auf die Grammatik.

Außerdem ist es im Deutschen – ebenfalls wie in vielen anderen Sprachen – gestattet, ein Adjektiv zu substantivieren, damit es eine Kombination aus Adjektiv und Substantiv ersetzen kann. Dabei bleibt der Kasus des ursprünglichen Wortes natürlich erhalten.

An deinem Beispielsatz ist also grammatikalisch nichts auszusetzen.

Comment: Kleines Detail: Nach [§58-5](http://www.canoo.net/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/GrossKlein/pgf57-58.html#pgf58-5) der amtlichen Regeln kann man _anderer_ hier zwar auch groß schreiben, aber der Normalfall wäre die Kleinschreibung.